# How to bind to only specific fields only on form object in symfony2 and Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am having a great problem.

I have the form on the site where I have two fields: `taskName` and `taskNote`.

I am not using the symfony form widget for displaying form but i am generating form fields by hand.

I have only generated field for `taskNote` in input text field and i am just using `taskName` as Label in Label fields instead of text box.

The problem is if i do that the answer is correctly going in database but all taskName are set to null

how can fix that

Comment: You can create a "hidden" field to store the taskName and then get it in the post php script.

Comment: i did that and it was working but is there any other way because this way if someone can change the field with firebug then my tasks will get changed as they are same for all users

Comment: well, i you want handle this in the server site you can store the id/taskName in the Session var

Comment: Problem is i have collections of multiple forms. Is there any way that i can remove that field somehow from binding

Comment: hmm do you want to remove the field? or just send the taskName securely to the post script?

Comment: I think it will be good if i remove the field because i just want to use as label thats it. Then i won't worry about data update in main table